# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'to_dict' for Discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@bot.command()
async def catto(ctx):
  choice = ["1","2"]
  print(random.choice(choice))
  if choice == 1:
    r = requests.get("APILINK").json()
    cat_embed = discord.Embed()
    cat_embed.set_image(url=r["url"])
    await ctx.send(embed=cat_embed)
  else:
    file = discord.File("FILEPATH")
    file2 = discord.File("FILEPATH")
    cats = (file, file2)
    await ctx.send(embed = random.choice(cats))
```

It's in the else bit Im having problems where it gives me the error as said in the title.

Full Traceback as suggested:

Ignoring exception in command catto:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Programming-Extra\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "c:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Programming-Extra\Discord Bot\BOTNAME", line 46, in catto
> await ctx.send(embed = random.choice(cats))
> File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Programming-Extra\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1017, in send
> embed = embed.to_dict()
> AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Programming-Extra\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
> File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Programming-Extra\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Programming-Extra\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'to_dict

Comment: Can you display the full traceback?

Comment: The last line should be ```await ctx.send(file=random.choice(cats))```, try it out...

Comment: you are using ```to_dict()``` attribute to a file instead of embed and its not in your above mentioned code

Comment: @GhostOps is right, if I understand well, the problem is that a file was named embed (the last line of the first error)

Comment: @sometalldude do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 1):

## Fix

---

The error is with the last line:

```
await ctx.send(embed = random.choice(cats))
```

It should be like this instead:

```
await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(file=random.choice(cats))
```

or like this:

```
await ctx.send(file=random.choice(cats))
```